# Cant seem to get the routing right in this vue.js portfolio I have been working on

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am working on building my portfolio right from scratch. Always used libraries and code snippets, but Vue seems to be a really cool framework which I want to master. Went over the basics and routing and everything. The first thing I want to do is put an interactive background for which I am using this - http://codepen.io/anandharne/pen/OpdrGE

**Index.html and Index.js and routes.js files**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>myportfolio</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <app>

     </app>

</div>
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>
</html>

import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes' 

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new VueRouter({
mode: 'history',
routes,
});
export default router;
```

**Hello.vue**

```
    <template>

    <div id="aa_particles">



  </div>
</template>

<!-- Add 'scoped' attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->

<style>
#aa_particles
{
    z-index: 4;

    height: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

    background: #222;
}

</style>

<script src="particles.js"> 

var x = ('aa_particles', {
  'particles': {
    'number': {
      'value': 80,
      'density': {
        'enable': true,
        'value_area': 800
      }
    },
    'color': {
      'value': '#ffffff'
    },
    'shape': {
      'type': 'circle',
      'stroke': {
        'width': 0,
        'color': '#000000'
      },
      'polygon': {
        'nb_sides': 5
      },
      'image': {
        'src': 'img/github.svg',
        'width': 100,
        'height': 100
      }
    },
    'opacity': {
      'value': 0.5,
      'random': false,
      'anim': {
        'enable': false,
        'speed': 1,
        'opacity_min': 0.1,
        'sync': false
      }
    },
    'size': {
      'value': 3,
      'random': true,
      'anim': {
        'enable': false,
        'speed': 40,
        'size_min': 0.1,
        'sync': false
      }
    },
    'line_linked': {
      'enable': true,
      'distance': 150,
      'color': '#ffffff',
      'opacity': 0.4,
      'width': 1
    },
    'move': {
      'enable': true,
      'speed': 6,
      'direction': 'none',
      'random': false,
      'straight': false,
      'out_mode': 'out',
      'bounce': false,
      'attract': {
        'enable': false,
        'rotateX': 600,
        'rotateY': 1200
      }
    }
  },
  'interactivity': {
    'detect_on': 'canvas',
    'events': {
      'onhover': {
        'enable': true,
        'mode': 'grab'
      },
      'onclick': {
        'enable': true,
        'mode': 'push'
      },
      'resize': true
    },
    'modes': {
      'grab': {
        'distance': 140,
        'line_linked': {
          'opacity': 1
        }
      },
      'bubble': {
        'distance': 400,
        'size': 40,
        'duration': 2,
        'opacity': 8,
        'speed': 3
      },
      'repulse': {
        'distance': 200,
        'duration': 0.4
      },
      'push': {
        'particles_nb': 4
      },
      'remove': {
        'particles_nb': 2
      }
    }
  },
  'retina_detect': true
})

</script>
```

Directory structure - https://i.stack.imgur.com/D71Z7.jpg

Should I create a new component by code? And how to put data in data field for new instance?

There is another file particles.js whose data can be seen at particles.js official github. Cant post another link because of reputation issues. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

**The code according to my fellow friend suggested**

```
    <!-- <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>myportfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>

        <app>

         </app>

    </div>
  <script src="../build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
 -->
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>ParticleJS</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo">
    <p> {{message}} </p>
    <input v-model="message">
</div>
<style type="text/css">

body {
  margin: 0;
  font:normal 75% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #222;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #b61924;
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}


</style>
<script src="http://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
<script src ="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
// /* eslint-disable */
// import Vue from 'vue'
// import Hello from './components/Hello.vue'
// import router from 'router'

// Vue.config.productionTip = false

// new Vue({

//   el: '#app',
//   router,
//   components: { Hello }

// })
/* eslint-disable */
var data = {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
}

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: data,
    mounted(){
        console.log('mounted');
      particlesJS('demo', {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 380,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 140,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});
    }
})
```

Comment: Forgot to put any errors: eslinting errors no unused vars and no spaces which I can decode, but is my routing right? Becasue it says Cannot get .. on the homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use particle.js background on all your app, then you could initialize it on your root component, and load particle.js on your index.html

Here is an example of particle.js working with vue.

```js
var data = {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
}

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: data,
    mounted(){
     console.log('mounted');
      particlesJS('demo', {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 380,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 140,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});
    }
})
```

```css
/* ---- reset ---- */

body {
  margin: 0;
  font:normal 75% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #bada55;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #b61924;
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>ParticleJS</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo">
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <input v-model="message">
</div>
<script src="http://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As like example, you should initialize particle.js on `mounted` hook.
Also initially try to create a single page without using route, then when you have more pages add routes. And make sure to read official documentation. https://router.vuejs.org/en/

Comment: Hi thank you for your input. I decided to not use routing since its a beginning. I get a get error on main.js although I have included its script src in index.html. The code:

Comment: On your original question, you are loading script like this `<script src="particles.js"> ` and adding additional script inside, which highly not recommended, please don't mix script loading and additional script in a single script tag. What error you are getting ? where you added code for particle.js?

Comment: I can run this in individual files with no webpack config, but can you tell me how to run this with using vue cli, I want to implement this using vue cli and I am not able to get it

Comment: Check this https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/issues/114 or try creating an issue on github, if nothing works one hacky way to do this is load `particles.js` on your index file.

Comment: you mean the index.html?

Comment: Yes I meant index.html

Comment: How do I do that with my use of vue cli and webpack intact?

Comment: Im sorry if I m asking rookie questions

Comment: Add a script tag below your app container, `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"
 type="text/javascript">`, this is not the best way to do it, but it would work.